# Percent of Total field in Salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq, quote, product, pricebook, cpq-api

I am trying to learn Salesforce CPQ where I have two questions. I have tried to create a Percent of Total product.

I have two questions here :

1. I will have to add the Percent of Total product in the Price Book where I am mandatorily supposed to add the list price. My question is what is this list price. Should I assign any random value to it just because its mandatory? or am I approaching this wrong and I wouldn't have to add Percent of Total field to the Price Book at all?
2. Can I specifically set Percent of Total product as a yearly priced product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up percent of total product, you do need to create a price book entry with a price. It doesn't really matter what you put in there unless you want to have a minimum or maximum price for the percent of total product (you'd use the Percent of Total Constraint Field in that case).

For your second question: you can have percent of total on yearly products. If you are running into a specific problem, I'd recommend a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.